# NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 \ recursive bisections in x near {x}. Why?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute an integral $\omega$ and evaluate the quantity $\pi/\omega$ to 100 figures:

```
f[x_] := 1/Sqrt[1 - x^4]
\[Omega] = 2*NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
N[\[Pi]/\[Omega], 100]
```

However, Mathematica shows me this message: `NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 \ recursive bisections in x near {x} =...`

Where this error comes from? How can I fix it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: (1) For this particular simple example, you can use `Integrate` because it can be analytically calculated as `ω = (2 Sqrt[π] Gamma[5/4])/Gamma[3/4]`. (2) When a message is generated, you can click three red dots and then read the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NIntegrate/ncvb.html) about this particular error. There you will find an explanation and possible solution (increasing `MaxRecursion`). (3) There are already some questions on this StackExchange about the error [`NIntegrate::ncvb`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NIntegrate%3A%3Ancvb).

Comment: (1) It comes from needing a lot of sample points to obtain the requested precision. (2) Mathematically, it comes from the singularity at $x=1$. (3) There are many ways to fix it, depending on your requirements for the approximation, which can only be guessed from `WorkingPrecision -> 100` -- 50 digits precision? 100? If 100, try the option settings `PrecisionGoal -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 200`.

Comment: Or you could use a substitution to remove the singularity: `\[Omega] = 
 2*NIntegrate[Cos[u] /Sqrt[1 - Sin[u]^4] , {u, 0, Pi/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Domen Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

"13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 1/Sqrt[1 - x^4]
```

As Domen pointed out, the integral can be done exactly

```
ω = 2*Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // FunctionExpand

(* Gamma[1/4]^2/(2 Sqrt[2 π]) *)
```

And, if done numerically

```
2*NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1},
  MinRecursion -> 10,
  MaxRecursion -> 20,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 2.6220575542921198106 *)
```

Using [`AskConstants`](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) to identify this numeric value provides
[image]

```
ω2 = 2 EllipticK[-1] // FunctionExpand

(* Gamma[1/4]^2/(2 Sqrt[2 π]) *)
```

This is identical to the analytic result

```
ω2 === ω

(* True *)

Pi/ω // N[#, 100] &

(* 1.19814023473559220743992249228032387822721266321565155826367495294640\
5214143915670835885556489793389 *)
```